# Use compass remotely

Tags: css, unix, textmate, sass, compass-sass

I have a problem using compass-style remotley over ssh and my favorite text-editor textmate.
IS there somehow to put a delay on the actual compiling of the sass-files? I think the problem is that compass recognizes that the files are changed and instantly tries to create the css, but this is happening while my text-editor still is saving, which results in broken files.

So the question is, is it possible to delay the creation of the files or solve this in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to the problem!

In the configuration of textmate it was possible to tick a box saying "use atomic save" which means that the program creates a temproary files, saves to the the temporary files, removes the old file and replaces it with the new one. This way compass can work just as excpected!